# Is it possible to hide the invoke popup if it is not called? python

Tags: python

My question sounds a bit messy. I do not want to show the invoke popup on the right side of the screen when it is not executed. I have added two conditions in the invoke function in the first condition it will pop up on the button but I don't want it to pop up when the second condition is executed. In the second condition, it is popping up on the right side of the screen that I don't want it.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
import bpy

class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom".upper()
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR.bl_idname)
        
class CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Adds Cubs"
    bl_idname = "custom.adds_cube"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER","UNDO"}
    
    def invoke(self,context,event):
        cube_is_there = False
        for obj in context.view_layer.objects:
            if "Cube" in obj.name:
                cube_is_there = True
        
        if cube_is_there == True:
            return context.window_manager.invoke_popup(self)
        else:
            return self.execute(context)
        
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="The Cube is already there in the scene.")
        
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        return {"FINISHED"}    
    
classes = [CUSTOM_PT_PANEL,CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: remove `UNDO` from `bl_options`

Comment: It is not undoing. I want to `UNDO` also.

Comment: use `self.report()` instead of `invoke_popup`.

Comment: I'll add an `operator` and some `properties` in the draw function that I want to hide from others. I already know about `self.report()`.

Comment: please clear up your question.

Comment: there is a popup because the `Cube` object is already in the scene.

Comment: In the second condition i.e. `else` condition, there is no popup. share a video

Comment: in the `else` condition there is no pop but it was showing on the right side of the screen. After changing `UNDO` to `UNDO_GROUPED`. The right side disappeared.

Comment: are you talking about the left bottom undo panel?

Comment: In your question `Is it possible to hide the invoke popup if it is not called?`, why there will be popup if it is not called?

Comment: Why are you calling it `right` side? Undo panel is located in `left bottom` side.

Comment: This question is an oxymoron.

Comment: bl_options = {"REGISTER","UNDO_GROUPED"}

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy


class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom".upper()
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR.bl_idname)


class CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Adds Cubs"
    bl_idname = "custom.adds_cube"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER","UNDO"}
    
    def invoke(self,context,event):
        cube_is_there = False
        for obj in context.view_layer.objects:
            if "Cube" in obj.name:
                cube_is_there = True
        
        if cube_is_there == True:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "The Cube is already there in the scene.")
            return {"FINISHED"}
        else:
            return self.execute(context)
        
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        return {"FINISHED"}    
    
    
classes = [CUSTOM_PT_PANEL,CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR]


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer from the API documentation. At the `bl_options` it should be `UNDO_GROUPED` instead of `UNDO`.

It is working as I was looking for.

````
import bpy

class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom".upper()
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR.bl_idname)
        
class CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Adds Cubs"
    bl_idname = "custom.adds_cube"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER","UNDO_GROUPED"}
    
    def invoke(self,context,event):
        cube_is_there = False
        for obj in context.view_layer.objects:
            if "Cube" in obj.name:
                cube_is_there = True
        
        if cube_is_there == True:
            return context.window_manager.invoke_popup(self)
        else:
            return self.execute(context)
        
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="The Cube is already there in the scene.")
        
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        return {"FINISHED"}    
    
classes = [CUSTOM_PT_PANEL,CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````